# Detect data changes and update redux persist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I know we can use redux-persist for saving our redux store in localstorage.
Let's say I have a API data which I want to save in redux-persist.
But problem is that let's say this data can be changed any time.

For example; I have a users list and I don't want to get this users list on every page refresh so I decide to save them in redux-persist. But what will be happen if the new user added to db and I want to see this user also in my users list. How can I do this ? Is that even possible ? It's look like silly question I know because if I want to detect new users I have to make a call anyway :D  I just want to know is there anyway for that ?

Comment: It depends on how immediate you want the change to be replicated to your application. Do you need it to be immediate? Would you like to maybe refresh your users list every 5 minutes?

Comment: Let's say in 15 minutes, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: If I were you, I would just write a function to make the request and cache the result in redux / redux-persist, and then write something else to call that function every 15 minutes (you'll have to choose if you want to also call the function on app load or just start off using the persisted state)

Comment: I found the library called "redux-persist-expire" you can set your expire time for redux-persist. Maybe that's what I am looking for or maybe I can save my data to sessionstorage instead of localstorage.